# when i do an update, I get these warnings

Tags: package-management, 16.04

is this an issue? 16.04

```
sudo update-manager -c
[sudo] password for charles: 
/usr/bin/update-manager:28: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/UnitySupport.py:29: PyGIWarning: Dbusmenu was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Dbusmenu', '0.4') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Dbusmenu, Unity
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/UnitySupport.py:29: PyGIWarning: Unity was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Unity', '7.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Dbusmenu, Unity
```

Comment: Looks like a bug, I would report it.

Comment: It is here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1573177

Answer (score 1):

No, it's nothing serious.

The programmers forgot to add a few lines of code that are needed now but not in previous releases.  But that just causes this warnings to be displayed.